# Is there any possible log separate files for different package in the Glassfish

Tags: logging, glassfish, java.util.logging

We are using glassfish as our application server. We want to log messages separately. 
For example if the log from xxx.company.xxx.service package, the log file is named as service.log, and if the log from xxx.company.xxx.dao, the log file is named as dao.log.

Right now, all the log message are printed to server.log file which is the glassfish server log file.

I know glassfish is using java.util.logging API, how to configure the log.propeties file and how to use this logger API. Does glassfish have similar functionality like Apache Tomcat Juli logger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FileHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html) doesn't support generating file names by package name from the LogManager.  The [com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/abluk.html#scrolltoc) doesn't seen to support it either.

If you want to generate a file name per each package you can create a custom [Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html) that will create and close a FileHandler on each publish.

```
public class PackageNameFileHandler extends Handler {


@Override
public synchronized void publish(LogRecord r) {
    if (isLoggable(r)) {
       try {
           FileHandler h = new FileHandler(fileName(r), Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1, true);
           try {
               h.setLevel(getLevel());
               h.setEncoding(getEncoding());
               h.setFilter(null);
               h.setFormatter(getFormatter());
               h.setErrorManager(getErrorManager());
               h.publish(r);
           } finally {
               h.close();
           }
       } catch (IOException | SecurityException jm) {
           this.reportError(null, jm, ErrorManager.WRITE_FAILURE);
       }
    }
}

@Override
public void flush() {
}

@Override
public void close() {
    super.setLevel(Level.OFF);
}

private String fileName(LogRecord r) {
    try {
        String cn = r.getSourceClassName();
        if (cn == null) {
            cn = String.valueOf(r.getLoggerName());
        }

        //Find package name.
        int index = cn.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (index > -1) {
            cn = cn.substring(0, index);
        }
        return new File(cn).getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException invalidFileName) {
        return "unknown.log";
    }
}}
```

A much faster version would create a pool of handlers on demand but, this is easier to write up.