# Generics in Java array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

To start with there are multiple posts on SO itself which explain why Generics and arrays do not mix in Java.

Like [Generic arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817524/generic-arrays-in-java)

But my question is - if that is so why do I get a warning in Eclipse when I do something like the following and how to get rid of this warning message.

```
private RotatingQueue<RotatingQueueData> rQueue[] =  new RotatingQueue[15];
```

Warning: 
Multiple markers at this line
    - Type safety: The expression of type RotatingQueue[] needs unchecked conversion to 
     conform to RotatingQueue[]

Comment: What happens if you change the right hand side of the assignment to `new RotatingQueue<RotatingQueueData>[15]` ?

Comment: Even better: `new RotatingQueue<>[15]`? (Java 7 is out, even Java 8)

Comment: Yes, I know, but I didn't want to introduce a new unknown, given that we don't know what version Andy is running.

Comment: @DavidWallace & LutzHorn Neither of those would work. Creation of array of parameterized type is not allowed.

Comment: @Rohit .. So I have to live with the warning ?

Comment: @Andy897 Yup. You can suppress it though. Even better would be avoid create array of parameterized types. Rather use `List<RotatingQueue<RotatingQueueData>>`.

Comment: Thanks !! I have another pending doubt regarding setting log levels (java.util.logging). I am trying to find a way so that I can specific the log level in my properties file and change it for the whole web app using that. Here is the SO link to it   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729271/setting-java-log-levels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to create an array of a parameterized type. Hence you have to live with the warning, but may ignore it like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<String> lists[] = new List[15];
```

I don't know about any other way to do this if you try to continue to work with `List<String>`.