# File Handler doesn't start working until i have a file created

Tags: java, logging, config, filehandler

I have a loggers.config file that specifies a custom file handler to format log messages to a file. The handler wont work unless a create a default file with the specified file pattern. It then creates a new file with a 0 appended to it as specified by the pattern and starts logging to that. How can I get it to log to a file without specifying a default file first.

Here is the logging file:

```
handlers=com.daniel.logging.MyFileHandler

# Default global logging level.
# This specifies which kinds of events are logged across
# all loggers.  For any given facility this global level
# can be overriden by a facility specific level
# Note that the ConsoleHandler also has a separate level
# setting to limit messages printed to the console.
.level= INFO

com.daniel.logging.MyFileHandler.level=INFO

# Naming style for the output file: 
com.daniel.logging.MyFileHandler.pattern=daniel%g.log

# Limiting size of output file in bytes -defaulted to 1MB: 
com.daniel.logging.MyFileHandler.limit=1MB

# Number of output files to cycle through, by appending an 
# integer to the base file name: 
com.daniel.logging.MyFileHandler.count=10

# Style of output (Simple or XML): 
com.daniel.logging.MyFileHandler.formatter=com.daniel.logging.MyLogFormatter

# Limit the message that are printed on the console to INFO and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

In the installer (this is an application logging properties file there was a file created there is a line specifying the logger.config file as logger.properties. A couple of lines later a file was created and the command CMD [@] >> default_file 2>&1. I am not sure what that line does (I'm quite new to bash)

Comment: Can you update the question to include the loggers.config that doesn't work and the loggers.config that creates the file with 0 appened?

Comment: Does MyFileHandler extend j.u.l.FileHandler?

Comment: Yes FileHandler class is extended in MyFileHandler

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user account the program is executing under has write permissions to the file path.

> com.daniel.logging.MyFileHandler.limit=1MB

That should be changed to:

```
com.daniel.logging.MyFileHandler.limit=1048576
```

Your file pattern is using a relative path.  You should use a absolute path or use the patterns for the home or temp directory.  The FileHandler will fail to create a new log file [if the directory path doesn't exist](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6244047).  The directories have to exist before the FileHandler will create the log file.

If you want to SimpleDateFormat patterns in the file pattern you can do something like:

```
    public final class MyFileHandler extends FileHandler {

        public MyFileHandler() throws IOException {
            super(toPattern());
        }

        private static String toPattern() throws IOException {
            String defaultPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
            String p = MyFileHandler.class.getName();
            String v = LogManager.getLogManager().getProperty(p + ".pattern");
            if (v == null) {
                v = defaultPattern;
            }

            try {
                return new SimpleDateFormat(v).format(new Date());   
            } catch (RuntimeException re) {
                throw new IOException(v, re);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you need rotation support you can reference [PackageNameFileHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447430/is-there-any-possible-log-separate-files-for-different-package-in-the-glassfish) as a starting point.

Comment: Is it possible to specify a FileHandler pattern that allows dates? for example if I had an initial file home-application which then had a date in the following format applied to it:$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)

Comment: The j.u.l.FileHandler doesn't support date patterns.  However, in your subclass it would be easy to create a static method to pre-process a j.t.SimpleDateFormat pattern from the file pattern before passing it off to the super constructor.

Comment: Would you have any links examples of this type of static method being created? thanks

Comment: What I actually have to do is add an iso 8601 timestamp to the end of each log file when they are created.

Comment: I updated the answer to include some examples for you.